# How to guarantee delivery of data in a Compact Framework Webservice call?

Tags: web-services, compact-framework, reliability

We have a mobile Application in a very unsteady WLan Environment. Sending Data to a webserver could result in a timeout or in a lost WLan connection.

How do we ensure, that our data is delivered correctly? Is there a possibility of having Web Services Reliable Messaging (WSRM) on the device?

MSMQ is no option at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSRM isn't supported.  A reliable mechanism is to ensure that either the Web Service responds to the upload with an ack after the data has been received (i.e. a synchronous call) or that when you start the upload you get back a transaction ID that you can then send back to the service at a later point to ensure that it has been delivered before local deletion.